# how can App Run on Full Screen Mode in android

Tags: android, fullscreen

I have created an app when I run It into tab then it is not taken full screen,I have also done its property"Full Screen With No title bar"So it is coming without title.

thanks

Comment: You should do some [search](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=android+make+acitivity+with+full+screen&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=adF&channel=fs&sa=X&ei=ssCGTtaJFpCurAeQ1oW4DA&sqi=2&ved=0CBkQvwUoAQ&q=android+make+activity+with+full+screen&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=a271f0478f23d1e9&biw=1280&bih=803)

Comment: refer to my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739353/webview-is-not-filling-the-whole-screen-of-device-or-emulator/5739694#5739694)

Comment: i Did this also but not working,its my twitter app so it is come on full screen but my Authorize page come on only Mid of screen and remaing screen is black

Comment: you can convert theme to translucent...so no black screen will be shown..

Comment: what is this Translucent..how can I use it

Answer (score 8):

you can add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` to the  `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: This is the correct answer - questioner, please mark as answer! Just worked for me. Also see: http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-make-an-activity-fullscreen